# Creating Topics on AzureServiceBus using MassTransit

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I have a namespace created in AzureSerivceBus. Directly, using Azure APIs, am able to create Topics and send-receive messages to it.

Now, I want to be able to create Topics using MassTransit as an abstraction layer. This is because for local installations, we use RabbitMq and MassTransit provides good abstraction. We now want the same code to move seamlessly over to Cloud (AzureServiceBus) and be able to perform the similar things. Is it possible to do it via MassTransit, i.e, create Topics and subscriptions to it?

The Azure document for MassTransit is very limited, so am not sure if it even supports Topics.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted correctly, MassTransit is an abstraction on top of the messaging service you choose to use. RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus, doesn't matter. The whole point is that it will provide you the features you need w/o burdening with details. Topic are commonly used for pub/sub (publishing events). While documentation for ASB is not as detailed as for RabbitMQ, there a section that states support for publishing messages using topics (http://masstransit.readthedocs.io/en/master/overview/publishing.html#routing-on-azure-service-bus).